# executing threads in POSIX

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am creating an asynchronous chat application in C. I created two threads, one for receiving and another one for sending as follows.

```
void* send()
{
...
}

void* receive()
{
...
}

main()
{
..
inid = pthread_create(&incoming,NULL,receive,"Incoming thread");
outid= pthread_create(&outgoing,NULL,send,"Outgoing thread");

..

pthread_join(incoming,NULL);
pthread_join(outgoing,NULL);

..

}
```

What the problem is, the send and receive functions are called only once and the program terminates. I want both the threads to run forever till the user wishes to exit ( the condition to check for exit is defined in the send function). How to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**One solution** is to have a `while(input != exit)` type of loop in *send*.

And make your main to only wait for *outgoing* thread (which means having pthread_join only for outgoing thread). So, when the user chooses to exit, the main will exit without waiting for the incoming thread.

Secondly, you need to use a *blocking receive* function in the receive function. So, it is either processing an incoming message or waiting for one.

**Another solution** is to have a `while(input != exit)` type of loop in *main*. Have a message queue defined in which *main* can queue messages to be sent and the *outgoing* thread consumes messages from this thread to actually send them.

The outgoing thread is either sending a message or is blocked until the queue has a message in it to be sent.

The input thread behaves in the same way as described in the previous solution.

Comment: @CHID: You can always vote and accept as a token of gratitude;)

Comment: oh sure.. sorry bout the delay ;)